# Run two vagrant boxes with different site versions

Tags: php, dns, vagrant

I'm using 2 vagrant boxes to run two different php versions (PHP5.4 and PHP7) on a websites codebase.

Both of these vagrant boxes sync the same folder.

How can I set these up to have the following domains:

```
PHP7:
php7.domain.com
local.domain.com

PHP5:
php5.domain.com
local.domain.dev
```

I also want the PHP5 box to run from the PHP7 box's database. What settings should I change here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a plugin to manage hostnames: [vagrant-hostmanager](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/vagrant-hostmanager/1.8.5)

here is how you can use it for both machines:

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|

  config.hostmanager.enabled = true
  config.hostmanager.manage_host = true
  config.hostmanager.manage_guest = true

  config.vm.define "php7" do |php7_config|
    php7_config.vm.box = "..."
    php7_config.vm.hostname = "php5"
    php7_config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.10.10"
    php7_config.hostmanager.aliases = [ "php7.domain.com" ]
  end

  config.vm.define "php5" do |php5_config|
    php5_config.vm.box = "..."
    php5_config.vm.hostname = "php5"
    php5_config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.10.20"
    php5_config.hostmanager.aliases = [ "php5.domain.com" ]
  end

end
```

After you run it it will place the records php7.domain.com, php5.domain.com in /etc/hosts